# How to give name to Pivot table in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, pivot-table

I have following Pivot table and I want to use it later in stored procedure.
So how can I give name to it or create/select pivot table to another table so that I can use it later in my stored proceudre.

```
select [2] as Feb, [3] as March, [4] as April from
(
  select entry1, month1
  from tblMonth
) d
pivot
(
  max(entry1)
  for month1 in ([2],[3], [4])
)  as ccc
```

I want to do "Select * from ccc", which I am not able to do it now.

Comment: You could use a cte if you only need to refer to it again in the next statement. You could insert into a temp table either by creating an explicit table or using select into.

Comment: yes, I would like to refer to it again in the next statement. Can you give me reference to cte example or syntax..?

Comment: Have you tried looking in a search engine? There are literally thousands and thousands of examples of ctes. I suspect though that you really want a temp table since you are talking about referring to the pivoted data more than once. Just add "into #MyTempTableName" before the FROM and you will have the results of your query in a temp table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested this, but the trick is to put a wrapper around the pivot table with an alias and then select from the alias. Something like this:

```
SELECT CCC.* FROM
(select [2] as Feb, [3] as March, [4] as April from 
(select entry1, month1 from tblMonth ) d 
pivot ( max(entry1) for month1 in ([2],[3], [4]) ) as c) AS CCC
```

There are plenty of excellent examples of pivot tables (just Google "pivot table sql server 2008 example").

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys, I got the following answer which I was searching for.

select * into tblMonth_temp2 
from 
(select ccc.* from
(
  select entry1, month1
  from tblMonth_temp
) d
pivot
(
  max(entry1)
  for month1 in ([2],[3], [4])
)  as ccc ) as x